# I did a newbie mistake and trashed my stick computer

Tags: computestick

Need some advice on loading my Intel stick computer running version 14.04. I trashed the internal micro SD with gparted, not double checking if it was the external micro SD card. So it is dead in the water, and I need to reload it, preferably as is would be in stock form.

I tried to load a bootable image onto a usb flashdrive, but the Stick computer would not boot it. I figured if I could boot, I'd just move the files system over to the internal SD drive.

The BIOS on the stick says it is only for use of Windows 8, and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. There was a post of the 'net for booting alternative operating systems, but the link to GOOGLE+ is dead. I guess the guy had a boot loader that would trick the BIOS of on the Stick computer. Thus, my need to help, trying to get this thing rollin, under the native OS, or updated, which would be fine.

Comment: 14.04 is past end-of-life so it's not supported, but maybe that's beside the point. What resources do you have for reloading the internal micro SD? What advice do you need exactly? What have you already tried and what have you found? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: The Intel STCK1A8LFC has 1G memory and 8G storage (incl 1G swap), so Lubuntu 16.04 is the best candidate for you, installed on a microSD or USB. Download and update the BIOs/firmware from Intel, and you should be able to boot either USB or microSD.  Forget 18.04+, too big/slow.  Full hw support requires kernel 4.19+. Debian 10 + the bluetooth firmware works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The Intel Compute Stick (ICS), STCK1A8LFC, was originally $110 when released
in 2015, but now is $35 from Amazon with free shipping. The UEFI stick
has an Intel quad core Atom (Z3735F @ 1.33GHz),  and comes with 1G
memory,  8G storage ( 48MiB EFI, 1.2GiB install, 935MiB swap, and 4.9GiB root), wireless 802.11bgn, Bluetooth 4.0, micro SD slot, USB 2.0, and HDMI output.  Not listed in the specs at all is the fact that it also comes with  64 bit Ubuntu 14.04.   The enclosed instruction sheet gives a firmware download site,
downloadcenter.intel.com, so download the stick's latest UEFI firmware
patch, FC0040.bio, and put it on a FAT/USB stick in preparation to flash
the stick. Flash the firmware before doing anything else, many
problems have been fixed.
  You will need a USB keyboard, and it must initialize quickly when powered up, because the time to press a function key is very short.  Use a powered hub if necessary (power usually not needed for just a keyboard, mouse and USB storage).

The firmware version and date on the shipped stick,
FCBT10H.86A.0024.2015.0522.1757, is now 16 versions out of date. This
information may be found by typing F2 at power-on (be quick at the
message), and going into the UEFI settings.

Download the OS independent firmware patch for STCK1A8LFC (FC0040.bio) from

```
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/86613/Intel-Compute-Stick-STCK1A8LFC  
wget https://downloadcenter.intel.com/downloads/eula/28922/BIOS-Update-FCBYT10H-86A-?httpDown=https%3A%2F%2Fdownloadmirror.intel.com%2F28922%2Feng%2FFC0040.bio
```

Hashcheck the download (MD5 supplied just above the download button).
Put the firmware patch, FC0040.bio,  on a USB stick with a FAT
filesystem, and with that in the hub, at boot, type F7 to flash the
firmware. Select the USB containing the flash file, then the
FC0040.bio file. Flashing takes about 5 minutes, and eliminates all
of the problems reported in the early reviews.  New firmware versions
are periodically released, so check back every few months for a new one
(for security updates).

The flashed stick should have no problems booting from the micro SD card or a USB stick in a hub, and installing to a micro SD card or USB stick.  The internal storage is limited to 7.1 GiB even if you resize the root to include the install partition (keeping the swap of 935MiB).  An Xubuntu install on a 16G USB is 6.4G, so it will fit, but you will not be happy with performance if swapping is  induced.  Installing Lubuntu or Xubuntu 16.04 to a micro SD card will make a usable system.  Putting a Debian 10 or AntiX 19 on the internal space results in a more responsive system.

The 4.19 kernel version has fully functional capabilities (HDMI sound, wifi, bluetooth) on this hardware. You will need to upgrade the kernel over the standard Lubuntu 18.04 to get bluetooth.  Use the hwe packages to put on the latest Ubuntu kernel.  Tailor the kernel boot line by adding "intel_idle.max_cstate=1 zswap.enabled=1 zswap.compressor=lz4" at the "quiet splash".

Comment: Thank you for helping me thru this. I got it up and running. Did have problems with the WIFI not being recognized during install, I have to sneaker-net two files, 1) the wpa_supplicant and 2) libpclight1 file. Otherwise It all went well. Thank you guys for the help!